# Override package default options

Tags: koma-script, typearea

I'm writing my thesis using the package `arsclassica` and the `scrreprt` document class provided by `KOMA-Script`.

`arsclassica.sty` in its implementation sets (line 14):

```
%************************************************************
% Text body
%************************************************************
\areaset[current]{370pt}{784pt}
```

Which tells the `KOMA-Script` to force that defined width-height text area p.44 of the KOMA bundle documentation `scrguien.pdf`.

I want to use my own dividing `DIV` as explained in par. 2.2 of the KOMA bundle documentation `scrguien.pdf`for the page layout but the following failed to set my own `DIV`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{DIV=15}{typearea}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=5mm]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
...
```

Nor worked

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=5mm]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[DIV=15]{typearea}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
...
```

Neither did

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=5mm,DIV=15]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
...
```

I have no errors in the log and I can't understand how I can ignore that command that arsclassica impose or override it with my preference.

Comment: You have to use `\KOMAoptions{DIV=15,BCOR=5mm}` after loading package `arsclassica` or you can use: `\AtBeginDocument{\KOMAoptions{DIV=15,BCOR=5mm}}`

Comment: @esdd that worked like a charm. However I didn't understood to use use it that way from he KOMA documentation. Is there any paragraph I missed maybe? Thank you very much!

P.S. If you want to post it as an aswerd to accept it do it.

Comment: [Early or late Selection of Options](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#section.2.4). And the alternative [`\typearea` can be found in the manual too](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-scrip/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:typearea.cmd.typearea).

Comment: I tried \typerarea too without success (second attempt example in the post). But missed that section, thank you very much for pointing it out. There are so many pages and section that I must have gotten lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\areaset[current]{370pt}{784pt}` uses package `typearea` to recalculate the page layout and the margins. So all previous settings of `DIV` will be overwritten by package `arcsclassica`.

If you want to use `DIV=15` you have to recalculate the page layout *after* the changes which are done by package `arsclassica`. You can use

```
\typearea[5mm]{15}
```

explicitly or set the KOMA-options `BCOR` and `DIV` using `\KOMAoptions`

```
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=5mm,DIV=15}
```

when package `arsclassica` is already loaded.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=5mm,DIV=15]{scrreprt}
\AfterPackage*{arsclassica}{\KOMAoptions{BCOR=5mm,DIV=15}}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that `arsclassica` loads and uses packages like `titlesec` and `tocloft` which break some KOMA-Script features. You will get warnings.